# How do I set a home page can be opened by anyone in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I set up the home page which can be accessed by anyone in Spring Security. However, when I enter `localhost:8080/home`, it redirects me to the page `localhost:8080/login`, and asks me to login. Could you please tell me what's wrong with the following code?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                        .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/home").permitAll()
                )
                .formLogin(withDefaults())
                .build();
    }
}

@Controller
public class AuthController {
    @GetMapping("/home")
    @ResponseBody
    public String home() {
        return "Home Page";
    }
}
```

The debug logs are:

[image]

I am using:

- Spring Security version 6.1.4
- Spring Boot framework version 3.1.4
- JDK 20
- Java 17

The **problem** is my Application file is not at root package.

The **solution** (thanks to Serghei Motpan) is add an explicit base package scan like: `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "package_name")`

Comment: please enable spring debug logs and edit your question to include the logs as it is impossible for us to know based on your description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated: Make sure to place your main class in the root package `chipbk10.com.example.authservices.Application`, or add an explicit base package scan, like `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "chipbk10.com.example.authservices")`
It sould solve the issue

(answer based on provided repo link: github.com/chipbk10/auth-services)